# Ansible: swarm role or two roles?

Tags: ansible

I want to follow best practices for ansible and use roles that match the features.

How to organize roles that have same commons but different usage? Let me explain this on an example of installing docker swarm.

Docker swarm may be installed as a `_master_` or as a `_node_`. Currently I have the `swarm` role. It has `main.yml` with tasks for **both** master and a node. Only by variables I determine if tasks is for a master, or for a node.

I dont like this. Instead of having variables, I would like to use hosts lists and say?

- serverA is swarm_master
- serverB, serverC... is swarm_node

This means I need two different roles, right? One for `swarm_master` and one for `swarm_node`. How I am going to share the same installation of swarm between these two roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:
Hosts:

```
[swarm-master]
serverA
[swarm-nodes]
serverB
serverC
```

Playbook:

```
---
- hosts: swarm-master, swarm-nodes
  roles:
    - role: swarm
      is_master: "{{ 'swarm-master' in group_names }}"
```

I think it's easier to understand the playbook, when you assign role parameters/variables when applying role.
It will be hard to guess for others that your role somewhere inside checks some variables.

To logically structure you tasks inside role, you may use conditional includes.
./roles/swarm/task/main.yml:

```
- include: docker_common.yml
- include: swarm_master.yml
  when: is_master
- include: swarm_node.yml
  when: not is_master
```

Comment: I dont see @knowhy suggestion?

Comment: I guess he's deleted his answer. I've updated mine with example.

Comment: One question - here you include docker-common. Then docker instalation is not a role, right?

Comment: No it's not a role in this example. I just wanted to illustrate, that you may include some common tasks for a role and then add conditional includes, based on parameter.

Comment: Thanx. Btw syntax for assigning roles in the first code block is not ok? It looks it should be  `- { role: foo_app_instance, dir: '/opt/a',  app_port: 5000 }`

Comment: You can do without braces, it's ok.

Comment: I think it might be better to make docker_common a role of it's own which is a dependency of both master and node roles